# How can I make vue-i18n / vue2 work with Storybook mdx type story?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, storybook, vue-i18n, mdxjs

I couldn't make it work for a long time so I thought to put here for others fighting with the same issue.

The setup is:

```
- "vue": "^2.6.12",
- @storybook/vue": "^6.4.19",
- "vue-i18n": "^8.22.4",
```

Following the i18n documentation I had updated my `preview.js` file to include:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);
```

Then I created the story for my component: `Avatar.stories.mdx`

```
<!-- Avatar.stories.mdx -->

import { Meta, Description, Canvas, Story, ArgsTable } from '@storybook/addon-docs';

import Avatar from '../app/js/components/common/Avatar';


<Meta
  title="Components/Common/Avatar"
  component={Avatar}
  argTypes={{
    username: {
      control: 'string',
    },
  }}
  args={{
    username: 'Tom Thomson',
  }}
/>

export const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  components: { Avatar },
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <Avatar v-bind="$props">
      </Avatar>
    </div>
  `,
});

# Avatar

<Description />

Basic style

<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Basic"
    args={{
    }}>
    {Template.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>

<ArgsTable of={Avatar} />
```

But this alone wasn't enough, `$t()` function was visible to my component used in the story because the function didn't get the context throwing errors like:

```
vue.esm.js:628 [Vue warn]: 
    Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_t')"
```

Really nothing more in the docs or Google that I could find.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was easy, but hard to figure out or to find.

To make `$t()` function work in your `.mdx` storybook story files you need two things:

- include `vue-i18n` in your `.mdx` file
- add `i18n` section to your `Template` configuration (in the same file)

and it goes like this - this is the working file:

```
<!-- Avatar.stories.mdx -->

import { Meta, Description, Canvas, Story, ArgsTable } from '@storybook/addon-docs';

import Avatar from '../app/js/components/common/Avatar';

import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

<Meta
  title="Components/Common/Avatar"
  component={Avatar}
  argTypes={{
    username: {
      control: 'string',
    },
  }}
  args={{
    username: 'Tom Thomson',
  }}
/>

export const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  components: { Avatar },
  i18n: new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: {
      en: messagesEn,
      ar: messagesAr,
    },
  }),
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <Avatar v-bind="$props">
      </Avatar>
    </div>
  `,
});

# Avatar

<Description />

Basic style

<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Basic"
    args={{
    }}>
    {Template.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>

<ArgsTable of={Avatar} />
```

I hope that helps someone.